# Telegram Conversation bot in python

Tags: python, telegram, chatbot, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am trying to make a conversation telegram bot in python.
I am trying to get the reply of the user and want my bot to reply him.
but the bot is not reading the new message except it keep send the previous text which is the bot command.

This is the function I am using:

```
def start(bot, update):
    username = update['message']['chat']['first_name']
    chat_id = get_chat_id(update)

    message = f"Hi {username} my name is Xeniour_Bot...\nHow are you?"

    message_id = update['message']['message_id']
    bot.send_message(chat_id, message, reply_to_message_id=update.message.message_id)
    time.sleep(5)
    reply = update.message.text
    bot.send_message(chat_id, reply, reply_to_message_id=update.message.message_id)
```

This is my main function:

```
def main():
    updater = Updater(botToken)
    dp = updater.dispatcher
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is the Output I am getting:

[image: This is the output]

Comment: Better show as you register the Command and Message handlers

Comment: I didn't understand, Are you talking about the main function in which I called all the commands. @Beppe C

Comment: I have added the main function, I guess you are prolly talking about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation of the CommandHandler needs to be corrected. The default MessageHandler implementation is also missing (unless you didnt copy in the question)

```
def start(update, context):
   username = update['message']['chat']['first_name']
   chat_id = get_chat_id(update)
   ...

def main_handler(update, context):
  logging.info(f'update : {update}')
  msg = update.message.text
  update.message.reply_text('Just received: ' + update.message.text)


# message handler
dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))    
dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, main_handler))
```

A good reference is the [Telegram Python echo example](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/echobot.py)

Comment: Yeah I did not add the message handler in it. But I have some problems can you send me a telegram bot that reply to the user "A small one" (if you have any example).

Comment: Yes, I have included an example (and reference) in the answer.